# Paste grep output horizontally

Tags: bash, grep, paste

I have a command `grep -A5 "Account:1\|Account:2\|Account:3" myfile`

Which gives me result like below

```
Sometext1 Account:1
Detail 1
Detail 2
Detail 3
Detail 4
Detail 5
--
Sometext2 Account:2
Detail 1
Detail 2
Detail 3
Detail 4
Detail 5
--
Sometext3 Account:3
Detail 1
Detail 2
Detail 3
Detail 4
Detail 5
```

Is there a way to paste this result horizontally. I know I can do it by 1st writing 3 files and then using `paste` but looking for a better solution.

Expected output

```
Sometext1 Account:1     Sometext2 Account:2     Sometext3 Account:3
Detail 1                Detail 1                Detail 1
Detail 2                Detail 2                Detail 2
Detail 3                Detail 3                Detail 3
Detail 4                Detail 4                Detail 4
Detail 5                Detail 5                Detail 5
```

Comment: can you show how exactly should look the final output?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest added

Answer (score 3):

With `GNU grep` and `pr`

```
$ grep -A5 --no-group-separator 'Account:[123]' myfile | pr -3t
Sometext1 Account:1     Sometext2 Account:2     Sometext3 Account:3
Detail 1                Detail 1                Detail 1
Detail 2                Detail 2                Detail 2
Detail 3                Detail 3                Detail 3
Detail 4                Detail 4                Detail 4
Detail 5                Detail 5                Detail 5
```

- `--no-group-separator` to avoid the `--` line between results
- the `-3` in `pr` indicates number of columns required

Answer (score 2):

#### With `paste`, under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
paste <(grep -A5 Account:1 myfile) <(grep -A5 Account:2 myfile) <(grep -A5 Account:3 myfile)
Sometext1 Account:1     Sometext2 Account:2     Sometext3 Account:3
Detail 1        Detail 1        Detail 1
Detail 2        Detail 2        Detail 2
Detail 3        Detail 3        Detail 3
Detail 4        Detail 4        Detail 4
Detail 5        Detail 5        Detail 5
```